# Validate mongoose input if one field is an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, joi

Having an already working sign-up functionality that creates user accounts based on email & password.

Mongoose model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

when a user is created it passes through a validation process using [Joi](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/):

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = {
  validateBody: (schema) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
      if (result.error) {
        return res.status(404).json(result.error);
      }
      if (!req.value) {
        req.value = {};
      }
      req.value['body'] = result.value;
      next();
    };
  },
  schema: {
    authSchema: Joi.object().keys({
      email: Joi.string().email().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required()
    }),
  },
};
```

Creating an user with Postman works fine:

[image]

The problem appears if I want to add a picture to the user when the account is created. As far as I know, it should be story as binary.

Added **image** in model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      image: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      }
    });

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Then added new line in validation:

```
 schema: {
    authSchema: Joi.object().keys({
      email: Joi.string().email().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required(),
      image: Joi.number().required(), //this line was added
    }),
  },
```

And tried to create a user in Postman. This time adding also an image and changed the Body to form-data and unchecked content-type: application/json.

[image]

As it can be seen, it returns an error saying the email is required. But the email is added on the key-value list, don't know why it cannot read it from there.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You are right, image should be stored as binary. But the type you should assign in mongoose for binary data is `Buffer` not `Number`. I don't know what you have to do for Joi

Comment: So I had changed it to `Buffer` in model. In Joi it seems it doesn't have that option so I put binary: image: `Joi.binary().required()`